# Termux - Cannot run python file in tasker

Tags: tasker, termux

I am trying to run a python file in termux for use in tasker. The termux tasker plugin requires an executable (you can't just run a command like "python something.py"). However, running chmod +x results in operation not permitted.

Here is a screenshot of the top of my python file, pointing to the python I installed via "pkg install python".

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Tasker has root access?

Comment: My phone isn't rooted. I thought that termux was it's own separate environment though. If the termux-tasker plugin requires an executable I would assume there would be a way of making an executable.

Comment: AFAIK, you need root for Tasker to access the `python3` binary file, because it belongs to Termux.

Comment: Is there any way to just run a termux command through tasker then? Surely tasker doesn't need access the the python binaries as it just tells termux to do it.

Comment: I'm afraid no, but why do you think Tasker is telling Termux to do it instead of doing it directly?

Comment: Because if tasker does it directly then what is the point of having termux in the first place.

Comment: You still need Termux to provide the full environment for `python3` to run correctly. You really think `python3` is a good binary to be run alone?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74433/discussion-between-theparanoidandroid-and-ibug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grant Tasker root access in order to let it run the script.

The script requires an interpreter, as specified in its shebang line. To run the script "directly", Tasker still needs to execute the interpreter, the `python3` binary. Since it's located in Termux's data directories, other apps can't access it without root access.

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but in case someone stumbles upon this and thinks its correct please note it is wrong.  You don't need root access!  You need Termux Tasker https://github.com/termux/termux-tasker